# Remove complete lines from string starting with roman numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I remove lines starting with roman numbers in this multi line string:

I. LIFE.

I.

SUCCESS.

Success is counted sweetest
By those who ne'er succeed.
To comprehend a nec...

Want help with python code, have tried below but now working:

for line in xtemp.split('\n'):
import re
if line.strip("\n") != r"\b(?=[MDCLXVIΙ])M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})([IΙ]X|[IΙ]V|V?[IΙ]{0,3})\b.?"
print(line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `re.sub` here in multiline mode:

```py
inp = """
I. LIFE.

I.

SUCCESS."""
output = re.sub(r'^[IVXLCDM]+\..*\s*', '', inp, flags=re.M)
print(output)  # SUCCESS.
```